# What does preg stand for in PHP's functions?

Tags: php, regex

Does anyone know what the `preg` in `preg_match`, `preg_grep`, etc. stand for?

I know they use PCRE, which are 'Perl Compatible Regular Expressions.'

Comment: I guess it’s an abbreviation for **P**erl Compatible **Reg**ular Expressions.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Perl REGular expression